# The adjoint representation of $U_q({\frak sl}_2)$ on itself

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

Let $U_q(\frak{sl}_2)$ denote the quantum universal enveloping algebra of $\frak{sl}_2$, and consider the adjoint action
$$
\mathrm{ad}_X: U_q({\frak sl}_2) \to U_q({\frak sl}_2),  ~~  Y \mapsto S(X_{(1)})YX_{(2)},
$$
where we have used sumless Sweedler notation. This gives $U_q({$\frak sl}_2)$ the structure of a $U_q({\frak sl}_2)$-module. What is the structure of this module? Does it decompose into a direct sum of finite-dim irreps, or are there infinite-dim reps in there? If decomposes into a direct sum of finite-dim irreps, then does every irrep appear, and are there multiplicities. How does it compare to the classical situation?

Comment: The quantized enveloping algebra is finitely *generated* but infinite-dimensional, so that answers at least some of your questions negatively.  Have you looked in Jantzen's quantum groups book?  If not, I think you'd find it very helpful, re how modules for U_q look.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see which questions are answered negatively by the fact that $U_q({\frak sl}_2)$ is an infinite-dim space. One can easily produce an infinite-dim $U$-module which decomposes into a direct sum of infinitely many fin-dim submodles.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't say "direct sum" in this context to include a case with infinitely many factors, but perhaps I've spent too long with fin dim algebras people. Re the question itself, have you looked at the subspace spanned by <H,H^{-1}>?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike what happens in the classical case, it is not locally finite dimensional, basically because it has invertible elements. However its ad-locally finite part $U'$ is very large and it decomposes as a direct sum
$$U'=\bigoplus_{V} V^* \otimes V$$
where the sum is over the irreducible finite dimensional modules (note this is a purely 'quantum' phenomena).

A standard reference is Joseph-Letzter "[Local finiteness of the adjoint action for quantized enveloping algebras](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939290157H)".

Comment: In what sense do you mean "dense"?

Comment: Also - I guess the sum is multiplicity free?

Comment: Sorry, dense wasn't the right word here, I'll edit. A precise sense in which it's large is explained in the linked paper. And yes, the sum is multiplicity free.